# Time delay in Mysql command

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I would like to execute a mysql command after 5 minutes after a click on the browser by the client.

Is there a way to achieve this in pure MYSQL ?

Is there a way to have a "queue system" as well ?

Execute 1 time  : run in 5 minutes

Execute 2 times : run in 5 minutes after the 1 time

Comment: You could use SESSION  or HTML Local Storage

Comment: In what context? A web app? On the server, without client interaction? Have you looked at cron jobs yet? What else have you tried? Post your code! What happens when you run it?

Comment: Client interaction

Answer (score 0):

SELECT SLEEP(5), detail on http://mysqlresources.com/documentation/date-time/sleep.

Having said that you should handle it in your application rather that database. If you do it on database less connection could be made and application pool maybe exausted.

Answer (score 0):

It would be preferable to seperate the things, to avoid timeouts and other nasty errors.

You could use cron, or similar, to schedule the execution of a PHP script, like this one:

`*/5 * * * * wget -O /dev/null -o /dev/null example.com`

Kindly borrowed from [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/619542/piping-wget-output-to-dev-null-in-cron).

It would be preferable to create a script that gets called by wget every 5 minutes, and create a table in MySQL for the queue, and add logic to the called script.